# Is there a way to implement ReLU without if statements?

Tags: math, optimization, boolean-operations, branch-prediction

I'm performing this operation a lot, and I want to avoid branch-prediction problems, so I'm asking here.

For signed integer values, using only integer or bitwise arithmetic, can I implement the following statement without an IF clause, or other control clauses? A preferable solution would be word-length independent.

```
if value < 0 {
    value = 0
}
```

Comment: The first thing to check is that that code really does compile down to a branch. It could compile to a conditional load. If it is a branch could try v *= (v>=0); or v &= -(v>=0); Whether these are actually faster of course could only be determined by measurement.

Comment: Not sure which language you're using, but if there's a built in "max" function you might get better performance than your `if`, e.g. `value = max(0, value)`.  This may already have some optimization, or if you're using a compiled language, the compiler may have some hints at an optimization.  Your friend in this case is to code up a number of approaches (including the nice one dmuir provides above) and profile them.  Before you do any of that though, you should verifiy this is a bottleneck in your program.  You may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @andand if I do that, I'll write an answer..

Comment: If you have an arithmetic right shift in the language you're using, `value &= ~(value >> (sizeof(value)*CHAR_BIT)-1) )` could work.  i.e. right shift to broadcast the sign bit, then ANDNOT.  Might be faster than booleanizing a compare result, especially on x86 with [BMI1 for `andn`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/andn).